# Why doesn't Samsung remove the non-essential software patent features to prevent patent war?

Tags: software

Commonly why doesn't patent infringer just remove the infringing features if they are not that important to their products. For example, in the [Samsung-Apple](https://www.cnet.com/tech/mobile/apple-v-samsung-patent-trial-recap-how-it-all-turned-out-faq) smartphone patent war, the software patents all seems very not essential for Samsung's success and removing them is not very hard, why doesn't Samsung just remove them to prevent the long-lasting war?

6,847,959 is a little bit difficult to get around since USB MTP protocal may be related which may be in the Android compliant test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The damages were for what was *already* sold. For future shipments they can either negotiate a license or remove the patented feature.